# How to link Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) with GNU Octave on Windows

Tags: windows-10, octave, blas, intel-mkl

I want to know the exact steps required to link Intel MKL with GNU Octave on **Windows**. I know that to do the same on Linux, I'll have to compile Octave (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-in-gnu-octave), but I would like to know the steps for Windows.

Comment: have you ever built GNU Octave for windoze?

Comment: No, never for windows. But I have compiled 64 bit Octave for Linux.

Comment: Have you succeeded with this? According to this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/891189 one could replace the Dynamic Libraries. Have you tried it on Windows?